# How to visualize actual hexdec in memory in visual studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Sounds crazy but in my class on Writing Secure Code the professor had us all configure or add a plugin to actually visualize the hexdec address values in memory for a process. We used it to define how to see the pointer that was the stack bound/offset and then fill the stack beyond that point. Just wondering if anyone is familiar with this capability in VS.

Comment: That was in 2007 and my memory is going.

Comment: Hard to guess why this requires a plug-in, Debug > Windows > Memory > Memory 1 shows raw memory content.  Debug > Windows > Registers is useful to see where the stack is currently located.

Comment: @HansPassant, Sorry you had to have a hard time guessing. In my Visual Studio 2015 Professional Debug menu I do not have a Memory or Register selection under Windows. Guess I'll research some more to figure out how to acquire this function.

Answer (score 1):

The watch window allows a great deal of configuration of how variables are displayed, for example, if you watch "variable,x" it will format the value in hex, if you do "variable,[10]x" it will expand it as an array of 10 hex values.

See more at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75w45ekt.aspx

Comment: Very interesting and useful.  I remember seeing the grid of memory locations displayed.  Probably this is a C++ plugin.